# How can I change the orientation of a document dynamically before printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I can get the priting dialogue to come up with javascript `window.print();` but I can't change it to landscape. is it possible with jquery or any way?

edit

if not, is there a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for IE6 but not IE7 or Firefox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var shell;
function SetPrintProperties() {
try {
shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.SendKeys("%fu");
window.setTimeout("javascript:SetPaperSize();", 1200);
window.setTimeout("javascript:setLandScape();", 2000);
} catch (e) {
alert('Please verify that your print settings have a Landscape orientation and minimum margins.');
}
}
function SetPaperSize() {
shell.sendKeys("%a{TAB}.2{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{ENTER}");
}
function setLandScape() {
shell.sendKeys("%fp");
window.print();
}
</script>
<body onload="SetPrintProperties()">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should let the browser handle the printing and just set a CSS specific for it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: what does this do? do i just put it in the head tag, and the browser will know if the page should be landscape or portrait when priting?

Answer (score 0):

This is a printer software specific issue, you won't be able to do this without significant hackery with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

function SetPrintProperties() {
try {
window.setTimeout("BLOCKED SCRIPTshell.SendKeys('%fu');",1);
window.setTimeout("BLOCKED SCRIPTSetPaperSize();", 1);
print();
} catch (e) {
alert ("An exception occured: " + e + "\nCode is: " + e.number + "\nDescription is: " + e.description);
alert('Please verify that your print settings have a Landscape orientation and minimum margins.');
}
}

function SetPaperSize() {
shell.sendKeys("%a{TAB}.2{TAB}0{TAB}0{TAB}0{ENTER}");
}

SetPrintProperties();

</script>
```

Comment: it doen't work. it says expected ';' at line 1 but i don't see any semi collons mission. which browser did you try it on? also is this spacific to any printer software?